# Cannot write or create files as www-data when using php exec

Tags: php, shell, apache2, exec, php-7

I have a question about the exec function on PHP 7.0.

I write a shell script to copy/sync the files and log the details into a log file, everything happens in the tmp folder.

```
# /tmp/data
drwxrwxr-x  4 root www-data  4096 Apr  4 00:00 data
# /tmp/data/data.log
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root www-data  9551 Apr  4 04:19 sync.log
```

I tried to login as www-data user for testing the shell script, and it works fine via command line but it's not good with PHP exec as below:

```
exec('sh /var/www/sync.sh');
```

I tried to dump the data and I am sure that I can touch the .sh file.

Is there anyone have ideas about this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Additional Info: There is no fail message like permission denied when I exec the shell script via PHP exec function, but it failed to write the log into the existing log file and the files failed to copy.

Comment: Does Apache have access to the sync.sh file?

Comment: Yes, i tried 777 with www-data user/group for the sh file.

Comment: Changing owner of file doesn't have any effect?